# How to post a content with an unknown length using a socket?

Tags: php

I made a program using google speech recognition api for my raspberry pi, in PHP CLI, and I would like to optimize it, sending the data while we are speaking (now it records what we are saying thanks to sox, then sends it).

So I would like to post the audio file to google while it is in writing, using sockets, but I am obliged to give the length via Content-Lenght before sending.

Is it possible to do otherwise? Not to give the length / to give a bigger max lenght ? Thank you. Here is my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html');

$name = 'www.google.com';
$dir = '/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=fr-FR&maxresults=10&pfilter=0';

$data = file_get_contents("/smart/voix.flac") ;

$envoi  = "POST ".$dir." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$envoi .= "Host: ".$name."\r\n";
$envoi .= "Connection: Close\r\n";
$envoi .= "Content-Type:audio/x-flac;rate=44100\r\n";
$envoi .= "Content-Length: 100\r\n\r\n"; 

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if($socket < 0){
        die('FATAL ERROR: socket_create() : " '.socket_strerror($socket).' "');
}  

if (socket_connect($socket,gethostbyname($name),80) < 0){
        die('FATAL ERROR: socket_connect()');
}

if(($int = socket_write($socket, $envoi, strlen($envoi))) === false){ //I send the first part
        die('FATAL ERROR: socket_write() failed, '.$int.' characters written');
}
    if(($int = socket_write($socket, $data."\r\n", strlen($data."\r\n"))) === false){//then the file
        die('FATAL ERROR: socket_write() failed, '.$int.' characters written');
}

$reception = '';
while($buff = socket_read($socket, 2000)){
$reception.=$buff;
}
echo $reception;

socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you adding `\r\n` to the end of the audio data?

Comment: Check here: http://mikepultz.com/2013/07/google-speech-api-full-duplex-php-version/

Comment: @squeamishossifrage i don't know, i saw it somewhere, so I just did the same, but maybe it's not compulsory..;

Comment: @DigitalChris Your link is to process an audio file which is finished, but yes, I use the old API, which is more direct without any api key.

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing:

```
$data = file_get_contents("/smart/voix.flac") ;
```

So at that point you must have a set file. So just:

```
$filesize = filesize("/smart/voix.flac");
```

and use that for Content-Length.

Comment: But he still needs to send the actual data.. If the content of $data and the given content-length differ, things might go wrong.

Comment: That was my point. Once you get the contents and put them in $data, they're not going to change.

Comment: In fact I would like to update the $data with the rest of the file content, while the user creates it.. So to send the first part of the data, then another.. whithout knowing when will it end.

Comment: You won't be able to use file_get_contents() for that.

Comment: hmm, I thought I would compare the old $data with the new file_get_contents, socket_write the new part of it, then restart (i don't know if you see what i mean)